# using pandas to parse a section inside a JSON document

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to analyze my electric bill usage (hourly data downloaded in JSON format! woot!) with pandas. I can do it, but it's klunkier than I expected:

```
import pandas as pd
import json

with open('test1.json') as f:
    j = json.load(f)
j2 = j['DailyBillingUsage']['RegisterCollections']['Channel']
s = json.dumps(j2)
d = pd.read_json(s, convert_dates='ReadDate')
d.ReadDate = pd.to_datetime(d.ReadDate)
```

I was expecting just to be able to do this:

```
d = pd.read_json('test1.json', something_to_guide_pandas)
```

but I can't tell it to use a subset `/DailyBillingUsage/RegisterCollections/Channel` of the document, and for some reason it won't automatically convert dates in ISO 8601 format (e.g. `2013-12-27T04:00:00-07:00`) even though I'm using the `convert_dates` parameter of `read_json()`.

Is there a way to do this without having to use the workarounds? (explicitly reading the document, pulling out the subdocument, and calling the `to_datetime()` function)

Comment: can you anonymize and post some of the data?

Comment: sure, i can do that. (will have to wait till i have some free time at home though)

Answer (score 1):

You can use my ObjectPath query language to do that:

**Python way:**

```
$ sudo pip install objectpath
$ python
>>> from objectpath import *
>>> with open('test1.json') as f:
...    j = json.load(f)
>>> tree=Tree(j)
>>> tree.execute("$.DailyBillingUsage.RegisterCollections.Channel")
-> the result here, a list of readings <-
>>> # some code to convert strings to dates
```

**Console way**

```
git clone https://github.com/adriank/ObjectPath.git
cd ObjectPath/ObjectPathPy
python ObjectPath -o file.json
(or python ObjectPath -u URLtoJSON)
>>> $.DailyBillingUsage.RegisterCollections.Channel
-> the result here, a list of readings <-
```

JSON doesn't have any date or time types so it is impossible to convert it automatically. Searching and guessing if a string is a date would kill the performance, thus you need to do it on your own.

When you post details about data you are working with, I will update this answer to fit your needs.

http://adriank.github.io/ObjectPath/